# How do I open the "Find Computers" dialog?

Tags: networking, active-directory, dialog

[image: Find Computers Dialog]

When using my computer this dialog appeared.

How can I open it?

Is there a shortcut I may have pressed or some reason this dialog would have opened?

In fact, when it opened, the following dialog also opened:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a shortcut I may have pressed or some reason this dialog would have opened?

> <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> is the shortcut that will open the Find Computers dialog (for Active Directory/domain joined PCs).

Source: [Shortcuts with Windows (Win) key every Windows 10 user should know](https://winaero.com/shortcuts-with-windows-win-key-every-windows-10-user-should-know/)